# Using Datastax DSE 4.0.3 I get an error when mapping a timeuuid in solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I have a column family that contains a timeuuid as an id for the column (it's a time series) and several other columns that make up the partition key. It also contains unsorted columns containing data that should be searchable (via solr).

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    unique_serial bigint,
    time_period int,
    event_id timeuuid,
    search_field_1 int,
    search_field_2 double,
    search_field_3 double,
    summary text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY((unique_serial, time_period), event_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_id DESC);
```

My solr schema looks like this:

```
<schema name="events" version="1.1">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongField" />
        <fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" /> 
        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntField" />
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                 <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" />
    </types>
    <fields>
    <field name="unique_serial" type="long" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <field name="time_period" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true" />
        <field name="event_id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="search_field_1" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="search_field_2" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <field name="search_field_3" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <field name="summary" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    </fields>

    <defaultSearchField>summary</defaultSearchField>
    <uniqueKey>(unique_serial,time_period,event_id)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

When I attempt to create the solr core I receive this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mismatch between Solr key field event_id with type uuid{class=org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer,args={class=solr.UUIDField}} and Cassandra key alias event_id with type timeuuid
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.validateUniqueKeyStructure(Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.java:235)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.update(Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.java:47)
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:244)
... 29 more
```

If I change the event_id to a UUID then it works but I want to keep the row ordered by the event_id. According to the documentation a UUID will do this if they are all of version 1 but I like how timeuuid is explicit about the importance of time and enforces version 1.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the datastax docs but I thought timeuuid was supported (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug caused by the "CLUSTERING ORDER BY" directive, please try without it and let us know.

Comment: So it's definitely a bug with the clustering order directive and TimeUUIDs, we'll include a fix in the upcoming 4.0.x release.

Comment: Does Solr sort propery over a UUIDFiled (TimeUUID) now? Looks like it ignores time nature of the values.